# Is there any way to prep a connection in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a backend Node.JS server which preps pages for output to a client's browser. It basically compiles HTML files, along with queries and combines them into a single file.

The issue I'm having at the moment is that to load a page, I might have to do multiple queries with `mongoose`. To summarise my code:

```js
// Imports up here for mongoose, express and mongoDB models

mongoose.connect(process.env.mongooseUri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    let article = await Article.findOne().lean().populate('category').exec();
    let category = await Category.find({ "name" : req.params.category ).lean().exec();
    let series = await Series.find({ "name" : article.seriesName }).lean().exec();
});
```

What I am finding is that each `find` request I make here is adding about 100ms, sometimes more, to the time taken to process the page.

In experimenting, what I found was `populate` is actually really fast, and it's much faster than doing `find` many times over. In tests I did, `populate` was often more than 10 times faster than doing multiple `await find()` requests.

It made me think that maybe the `100ms` being added for each request is not to do with the time it takes mongoDB to run `find()`, but rather it's warm up time to connect to the DB.

So my question is, is there a way to make these queries faster? Since `populate` is so fast, is there some way I can leverage the same speed on a regular individual `find()` request so I am not wasting 100ms each time running these `find` requests?

I am getting to the point where because I am doing maybe 5 or 6 different `find` requests, the page load time is increasing by 0.8s. I figure I can figure out some smart caching solution, but I'm curious if this is the most efficient way to do `find()`.

Comment: If the delay is occurring every request, it likely doesn't have to do with the database connecting. Once it initially connects, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Do you have indexes set up on the properties you're querying by? If not, that could both add delay and make it take more resources.

Comment: I understand your situation however the problem here is to make so many request at one endpoint. So the solution is to separate these type of requests to separated endpoints. Or maybe you should reconsider your schemas and edit your relationships (one-to-one, one-to-many) in more efficient way that may require less request to achieve your goal.